# NSCFString objectAtIndex: unrecognized selector sent to instance Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, nsstring

I am trying to get some json data and show it as text in a UILabel but I keep on getting a app crash with the following error -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f8cfff0?

Here is my code and the json response. I see in my log that I am getting the Name from the call but the app bombs out the that error. I have 2 UILabel blocks, one of which shows a text format of the json response and the other the actual json response in text.

I'm trying to pull the name of the person, I can see Bilbo Baggins in the log when the json comes back.

Here is my json output:

```
{"ProfileID":34,"ProfilePictureID":20,"Name":"Bilbo Baggins","Clients":[{"ClientID":91,"Name":"Fnurky"},{"ClientID":92,"Name":"A different client"},{"ClientID":95,"Name":"Second Community"},{"ClientID":96,"Name":"Britehouse"}]}
```

and my code to try show it as a uilabel as text.

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.ddproam.co.za/Central/Profile/JSONGetProfileForUser"] //2

#import "JsonViewController.h"

@interface NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress;
-(NSData*)toJSON;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress
{
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] ];
__autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error != nil) return nil;
return result;
}

-(NSData*)toJSON
{
NSError* error = nil;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error != nil) return nil;
return result;    
}
@end

@implementation JsonViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kLatestKivaLoansURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}

 - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:&error];
NSArray* defineJsonData = [json objectForKey:@"Name"]; //2

NSLog(@"Name: %@", defineJsonData); //3

// 1) Get the latest loan
NSDictionary* loan = [defineJsonData objectAtIndex:0];


// 3) Set the label appropriately
humanReadble.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello: %@",
                     [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"Name"] objectForKey:@"Name"]];

//build an info object and convert to json
NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [loan objectForKey:@"Name"],
                      nil];

//convert object to data
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];

//print out the data contents
jsonSummary.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}

@end
```

Comment: `defineJsonData = [json objectForKey:@"Name"]` is the *string* "Bilbo Baggins", so why do you expect `[defineJsonData objectAtIndex:0]` to work?

Comment: Not sure. I'm just trying to show the json response name in my uilabel?

Comment: Your JSON contains `"Name":"Bilbo Baggins"`, therefore `[json objectForKey:@"Name"]` returns the string   "Bilbo Baggins".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of – sorry – poor var names and lost in a complex structure.

First:
Here you get the complete JSON as Dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:&error];
```

According to your Q, this has this structure:

```
{
   "ProfileID":34,
   "ProfilePictureID":20,
   "Name":"Bilbo Baggins",
   "Clients":
   [
      {
         "ClientID":91,
         "Name":"Fnurky"
      },
      {  
         "ClientID":92,
         "Name":"A different client"
      },
      {
         "ClientID":95,
         "Name":"Second Community"
      },
      {
         "ClientID":96,
         "Name":"Britehouse"
      }
   ]
}
```

Second:
With the next statement, you simply get the name of obviously something like a person:

```
NSArray* defineJsonData = [json objectForKey:@"Name"]; //2
```

There is the root:

what you get – look at your JSON – is:

```
   "Name":"Bilbo Baggins",
```

- You get the object for the key `Name`. The var, holding the reference to the result should be called expressing this. Let's change this:

  NSArray* name = [json objectForKey:@"Name"]; //2
- Next – look at your JSON – the object behind that key is an instance of `NSString`, not `NSArray`. Let's repair this:

  NSString* name = [json objectForKey:@"Name"]; //2

Third:

Doing so will the compiler make throwing out an error. This is because of this statement:

```
NSDictionary* loan = [defineJsonData objectAtIndex:0];
```

Changed to the new var name:

```
NSDictionary* loan = [name objectAtIndex:0];
```

The compiler is right: You do not have an array, so you cannot send `objectAtIndex:`.